# (Java ->Kotlin) How can I convert this code?(Stream, filter)

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a problem of Java --> Kotlin converting..
How can I convert this code?

```java
String[] allLongestStrings(String[] inputArray) {

    int mL = 0 ; 

    for(int i =0; i < inputArray.length; i++){

        if(mL<inputArray[i].length())
            mL = inputArray[i].length();
    }

    final int longest = mL;

    return Stream.of(inputArray)
        .filter(s -> s.length()==longest)
        .toArray(String[]:: new);    
}
```

I especially want to change this part.

```java
return Stream.of(inputArray)
        .filter(s -> s.length()==longest)
        .toArray(String[]:: new);
```

please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to make it this simple:

```
fun allLongestStrings(inputArray: Array<String>): Array<String> {
    val longest = inputArray.maxBy { it.length }?.length
    return inputArray.filter { it.length == longest }.toTypedArray()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var mL = 0;

    val inputArray = Array<String>();
    for (i in 0 until inputArray.size) {
        if (mL < inputArray[i].length)
            mL = inputArray[i].length
    }

    val longest: Int = mL
    inputArray.filter {
        it.length == longest
    }
```

**Java vs. Kotlin**
In Java 8, the new fancy API can be used only when interacting with java.util.stream.Stream instances.

The good thing is that all standard collections – anything that implements java.util.Collection – have a particular method stream() that can produce a Stream instance.

It's important to remember that the Stream is not a Collection. It does not implement java.util.Collection and it does not implement any of the normal semantics of Collections in Java. It is more akin to a one-time Iterator in that it is derived from a Collection and is used to work through it, performing operations on each element that is seen.

In Kotlin, all collection types already support these operations without needing to convert them first. A conversion is only needed if the collection semantics are wrong – e.g., a Set has unique elements but is unordered.

One benefit of this is that there's no need for an initial conversion from a Collection into a Stream, and no need for a final conversion from a Stream back into a collection – using the collect() calls.

[Reference](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-stream-vs-kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried IntelliJ automatic feature?

It would probably be something like:

```
    internal fun allLongestStrings(inputArray: Array<String>): Array<String> {

        var mL = 0

        for (i in inputArray.indices) {

            if (mL < inputArray[i].length)
                mL = inputArray[i].length
        }

        val longest = mL

        return inputArray.filter { s -> s.length == longest }.toTypedArray()

    }
```

Comment: Please do not use code snippets for non-JavaScript code. They are meant to **only* be used for HTML/CSS/JS stuff. Use normal code blocks for other languages.

Comment: Sorry, did not post in here for a long time, did not know it.